# Is it possible to restrict the maximum subsite level?

Tags: 2013, 2016, sub-site, content-and-structure

We are trying to enforce a flatter intranet structure, and are curious if it's possible to restrict the level of subsites you have. The type of structure we're going for is as follows:

```
Home
    Function/Department Public 1
        Function/Department Private 1 Home 1
        Function/Department Private 1 other 2
        Function/Department Private 1 other n
    Function/Department Public 2
        Function/Department Private 2 Home 1
        Function/Department Private 2 other 2
        Function/Department Private 2 other n
    Function/Department Public m
        Function/Department Private m Home 1
        Function/Department Private m other 2
        Function/Department Private m other n
```

Where you can only create as far down as a second level Subsite. This will make Org structure changes easier, make Managed Navigation easier to deal with, and make content harder to lose.

**Is it possible to restrict the highest level of subsites one can make?**

Currently we are using SP 2013, but we are in the process of upgrading to 2016 so knowledge on either would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with what Arin has mentioned about governance and there are various approaches to enforcing that.

But to answer your question you can also implement `WebAdding` or `WebProvisioned` event receiver and perform necessary validation in that code. You can refer to [microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebeventreceiver?view=sharepoint-server) for more information. See [this link](http://solutionz4u.blogspot.com/2012/01/attaching-web-event-to-perform.html) for example on how to implement web event receivers.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Chose yours as the answer because of its option for the web event receivers as it does more directly answer my question... It's a neat idea! But we may go with a governance model instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't specifically and explicitly limit the number of sub-sites, but a solution would be to limit the users who can create new sites and put in place a governance model wherein end-users have to request new sites and then a governance team can review whether it would violate the "corporate standard" of having more than, for example, 3 sub-sites.